# React component sends API Calls whenever loads

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

React component sends API call again whenever the homepage component loads with default empty values… I want whenever someone go to the settings page and came back without changes in settings, no new API Call will be sent. But if the user came from settings page after changing settings, then a new API Call will be sent according to changes… I don't want to use Session or local storage…  Because it's a random User API, so if I store there it would not be change after user reloads the Page.

```
  const users = useSelector((state) => state.users);
  const loading = useSelector((state) => state.loading);
  const search = useSelector((state) => state.search);
  const nationlity = useSelector((state) => state.nationlity);
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (nationlity) {
      fetchUseresWithNationality(nationlity);
    } else {
      fetchUser();
    }
  }, []);
  const loadMoreUsers = () => {
    if (users.length <= 999) {
      if (nationlity) {
        fetchMoreUseresWithNationality(nationlity);
      } else {
        fetchMoreUsers();
      }
    } else {
      setHasMore(false);
    }
  };
  return (<>My Content</>)
};
```

Comment: I'm using Link i also used the preventDefualt()... but facing same issue...

Comment: Try including nationlity in useEffect's dependensy array `useEffect(() => {...}, [nationlity])` . Then it only reloads when `nationlity` changes

Comment: Let me know if this solved the problem

Comment: This happens because the homepage gets unmounted when you navigate to settings(or any other) page. You cannot rely on variables/state internal to homepage component for this and you need a global state. You can use redux, or any other global state, or change a global variable on first api call.